# maintain appended logs in separate file despite tail command termination

Tags: logs, io-redirection, ps, tail, newlines

I have tomcat catalina.log file that keeps getting updated.

I wish to maintain its past 500 lines + any appended logs into a new file `catalina.log_new` for the next 2 hours.

To start off I run `nohup  tail -n 500 -F --retry catalina.log>>catalina.log_live`

The catch is that the above `tail` command may get terminated(for whatever reasons).

I tried the below logic but I'm not sure. I'm not writing the logic of how to run the below for 2 hours as it is not relevant to the problem.

```
nohup  tail -n 500 -F --retry catalina.log>>catalina.log_live

while true
do
    ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep tail | grep 500 | grep catalina.log
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        nohup  tail -n 1 -F --retry catalina.log>>catalina.log_live
    fi
  sleep 5;
done
```

Can you please suggest if this approach is decent and will result in no missing or duplicate lines and help gather past 500 lines and the new lines appearing for the next 2 hours from `catalina.log` into `catalina.log_live`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `nohup` or `ps`, simply run `tail` as foreground process, if `tail` terminates for whatever reason, so could its parent shell process, making the restarting commands useless. A better approach would be to create a service for this weird purpose.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# catalina_log_new.sh

{
    # sleep 2 hours, then kill parent process
    sleep $((2 * 60 * 60))
    kill $$
} &

# make sure alarm is killed when the script exits
_alarm_pid=$!
trap 'kill $_alarm_pid 2>/dev/null' EXIT

# first write last 500 lines
tail -n500 catalina.log > catalina.log_new

# then append new lines only
while true; do
    tail -F -n0 catalina.log >> catalina.log_new
done
```

Or instead of the background sleep you can use `timeout $((2 * 60 * 60)) ./catalina_log_new.sh` which will kill the script if it's still running after 2 hours.